# How to decrease body text size only in word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a text file with headings and body text and it is properly formatted in outline. Now I want to decrease only the body text size. As the document is very large, I don't want to decrease the size of all text, as this would mean that I have to adjust all headings manually.

How do I accomplish this in Word 2011?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Select text that is styled with the style attributes that you want to change.
>
>    For example, to change the attributes of the Heading 1 style, select
>      text that has the Heading 1 style applied.
> 2. Format the selected text with the new attributes that you want.
>
>    For example, you might decide that you want to change the point size
>      for the Heading 1 style from 16 points to 14 points.
> 3. On the Home tab, in the Styles group, right-click the style that you want to change.
> 4. Click Update to Match Selection.
>
> All text with the style that you changed will automatically change to
>   match the new style that you defined.

[Change the formatting of a style](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-formatting-of-a-style-3edc8f82-8ada-4592-afcb-5813bfb1ee99)

Comment: Thanks. Ok the key was in selecting that bit of body text. I could also right-mouse click then on the style and then select "select all occurrences". However I've modified it now to have 10 size instead of 12.